# Long to Wide Data - Every Nth row

Tags: r, reshape2, tidyr, rvest

I am writing up a new script where I pull (with `rvest`) an html table from a website. The data is a consistent format, but the values changes daily.

When the table is scraped in, it comes in long format. The data can logically be grouped though, and I want to take the data from long to wide format. There are 15 rows in between each new variable...is there a function, or using a package such as `tidyr`/`reshape2` that can be used to achieve desired results?

Quick example, with only consideration of 1 variable in the list:

```
A.1
A
Name A
-1
0
18:05
00:00
0:50
2
(no value presented, will replace with 0 in my code later on)
(no value presented, will replace with 0 in my code later on)
1
1
4
13
```

Desired result:

```
A.1  A  Name A  -1  0  18:05  00:00  0:50 2  0  0  1  1  4  13
```

And it will be repeated for approximately ~1000-1200 rows and I'll be running this code daily.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your dataframe,

```
df = data.frame(c("A.1", "A", "Name A", -1, 0, "18:05", "00:00", "0:50", 2, NA, NA, 1, 1, 4, 13,
                  "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8", "B9", "B10", "B11", "B12", "B13", "B14", "B15"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

you could bang it out in one line as follows (no need for any packages):

```
View(t(as.data.frame(split(df, (as.numeric(rownames(df))-1) %/% 15))))
```

From here you'll need to continue on...replace the `NA`s and modify data types, etc, as to your liking.